Time translational invariance of correlations from path integral
Consider a $1D$ field theory correlation from the path integral perspective as follows $$\langle\phi(t_1)\phi(t_2) \rangle = Z^{-1}\int [\mathcal{D}\phi]~\phi(t_1)\phi(t_2) e^{iS[\phi]/\hbar}.\tag{1}$$
Now, under a time translation $t_i \to t_i+\epsilon$ we have $$\delta_{\epsilon}\phi = \epsilon\dot\phi.\tag{2}$$
Now, let me look at $$\delta_{\epsilon}\langle\phi(t_1)\phi(t_2) \rangle = \epsilon Z^{-1} \int [\mathcal{D}\phi]~(\dot{\phi}(t_1)\phi(t_2)+\phi(t_1)\dot{\phi}(t_2)) e^{iS[\phi]/\hbar}.\tag{3}$$
I am assuming $\delta_{\epsilon}S[\phi] = 0$. So, no terms from the exponential. Now the question is how is the above expression supposed to vanish? Should there be some Jacobian terms from the path integral measure as well?

One can take one of the terms, transfer the time derivative to the other field and pick up a minus sign leading to a cancellation.

Hint: Use the Schwinger-Dyson (SD) equation$^1$
$$\langle \underbrace{\delta_{\epsilon}F[\phi]}_{=\epsilon_0\{\dot{\phi}(t_1)\phi(t_2)+\phi(t_1)\dot{\phi}(t_2)\}}\rangle ~+~ \frac{i}{\hbar} \langle F[\phi]\underbrace{\delta_{\epsilon}S[\phi]\rangle}_{=\epsilon_0\{L(t_f)-L(t_i)\}=0}~=~0,\tag{A}$$
with functional
$$ F[\phi]~=~\phi(t_1)\phi(t_2)\tag{B}$$
and infinitesimal variation
$$ \delta_{\epsilon} ~=~\int\! dt ~\underbrace{\epsilon(t)}_{=\epsilon_0}\dot{\phi}(t)\frac{\delta}{\delta\phi(t)}. \tag{C}$$

$^1$ The infinitesimal Jacobian in the path integral is formally proportional to $\delta^{\prime}(0)$, which vanishes in e.g. dimensional regularization (DR), cf. e.g. this Phys.SE post. Concerning boundary terms in SD equations, see e.g. this Phys.SE post.

Are you saying because $(C)$ leads to a total functional derivative in the path integral that is why it vanishes?

Essentially yes.
